# How to manage refresh token in JWT Token method in express?

Tags: express, access-token, refresh-token, passport-jwt

ex)
refresh token: A
acess Token : B

user acquistion : A, B

If B expires, use A to reissue B

So if the attacker steals A, doesn't he get B?

According to the rfc official documentation, I heard that the client has A and B, but I don't know if that's true.

I don't understand the mechanism of using the correct refresh token.

How should I shape the implementation direction?

1. I logged in and finished issuing refresh tokens and access tokens.

main question :  When accessing a protected page, when the access token expires and there is a refresh token, I don't know how to use it. I don't know if it's true that the problem of being stolen arises.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the access token and refresh token, most of the time you're using your username and password. the idea of using tokens is to use as last as possible in your credentials on transit to avoid credentials stolen.

the different in this two token in the ability to revoke the token, while in access token you're not able to revoke the token (if the token steals the attacker can do anything), as the refresh token (a.k.a - your session) can be revoked, to if this token stolen you can revoke it and no new access token will be generate.

best practice is to generate short expiration for access token (for the case it will be steals), long period for refresh token - in order not use your credentials a lot.